# set cancelable true in smali

Tags: java, android, smali

I was reverse engineering apk file and i found that theres AlertDialog is cancelable false

```
invoke-virtual {v0, v4}, Landroid/app/AlertDialog$Builder;->setCancelable(Z)Landroid/app/AlertDialog$Builder;
```

(in java code it shows cancelable false)

So i tried this code in my other app and compiled it

```
.setCancelable(true)
```

but it's smali codeline remains same

```
invoke-virtual {v2, v3}, Landroid/app/AlertDialog$Builder;->setCancelable(Z)Landroid/app/AlertDialog$Builder;
```

So how can i change cancelable to true in smali file.

Comment: Well it normally is. It's illegal to distribute code that is someone else's property. There are guidelines on how much change there needs to be before it's considered ok. But if you Inject Bytecode at runtime and distribute a program that does injection that is to my understand completely legal.

Comment: @jb15613 Hey guys it's not topic about legal and illegal just show me what's logic behind these similar like different outputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode_instruction_listings

If you do you can see that it uses the Constant Pool. You need to edit the Constant pool and make a new invokevirtual with your value you added to the constant pool.

Since you are probably new to the whole thing instead of my normal suggestion of BCEL or ASM I am going to give you a link to JBE, http://set.ee/jbe/

Answer (score 0):

`invoke-virtual` is a mnemo-code for Java's command to invoke virtual method of an object (pretty obvious). It uses from 1 to many "parameters" (or registers, strictly speaking) to perform the actual invocation. The first one is a pointer to an object which method you are calling and the rest of them are used to define values for that method parameters.
In your initial example `v0` and `v4` are pointer to registers (you can think of them as a local variables). So `v0` is a pointer to an object of the `android.app.AlertDialog.Builder` class. The `v4` register holds setCancelable parameter's value. It is impossible to say from this piece of code whether you invoking `->setCancelable(True)` or `->setCancelable(False)`, the smali-code of this part will be the same for both of them. The actual value for the method's parameter is set to `v4` register somewhere BEFORE this line of code. So you can probably see something like `const/4 v4, 0x0` a few lines above. That defines `False` value for the parameter. Change it to 0x1 and you are readi to apktool-it back to apk.

Some reading to consider: http://pallergabor.uw.hu/androidblog/dalvik_opcodes.html
https://code.google.com/p/smali/wiki/Registers